# Inconsistent values for %j across Systemd service and drop-in units

Tags: linux, services, systemd

On a Debian system, let's say I have an instance systemd unit `/lib/systemd/system/foo@.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=good old foo

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/env echo "%%i=[%i]   %%j=[%j] (from %n (foo@.service))"
```

I'd like to make a couple of small additions to `foo@.service` for my system.  Because the unit file is in `/lib/systemd/system` where edits are not recommended, I make a directory `/etc/systemd/system/foo@.service.d` (to do things by-the-book ) in which I create a file `additional.conf` containing:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/env echo "%%i=[%i]   %%j=[%j] (from %n (additional.conf))"
```

Reload the systemd conf and run `sudo systemctl cat foo@.service`:

```
# /lib/systemd/system/foo@.service
[Unit]
Description=good old foo

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/env echo "%%i=[%i]   %%j=[%j] (from %n (foo@.service))"

# /etc/systemd/system/foo@.service.d/additional.conf
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/env echo "%%i=[%i]   %%j=[%j] (from %n (additional.conf))"
```

This shows `foo@.service` has picked up my new `additional.conf` drop-in.

As you can see in the unit files, I'm making use of the `%j` specifier (this is the string between the last "-" and the end of the prefix name).  To make concrete use of this I create a symlink:

```
sudo ln -sv /lib/systemd/system/foo@.service /etc/systemd/system/foo-bar@.service
'/etc/systemd/system/foo-bar@.service' -> '/lib/systemd/system/foo@.service'
```

Reload the systemd conf and run `sudo systemctl cat foo-bar@.service`:

```
# /lib/systemd/system/foo@.service
[Unit]
Description=good old foo

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/env echo "%%i=[%i]   %%j=[%j] (from %n (foo@.service))"

# /etc/systemd/system/foo@.service.d/additional.conf
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/env echo "%%i=[%i]   %%j=[%j] (from %n (additional.conf))"
```

This shows `foo-bar@.service` has picked up my additions.  Now run `systemctl start foo-bar@baz.service` followed by `systemctl status foo-bar@baz.service`:

```
● foo@baz.service - good old foo
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/foo@.service; static)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/foo@.service.d
             └─additional.conf
     Active: inactive (dead)

Nov 01 12:10:31 Intel-NUC systemd[1]: Starting good old foo...
Nov 01 12:10:31 Intel-NUC env[56108]: %i=[baz]   %j=[bar] (from foo-bar@baz.service (foo@.service))
Nov 01 12:10:31 Intel-NUC env[56109]: %i=[baz]   %j=[foo] (from foo@baz.service (additional.conf))
Nov 01 12:10:31 Intel-NUC systemd[1]: foo@baz.service: Succeeded.
Nov 01 12:10:31 Intel-NUC systemd[1]: Finished good old foo.
```

You can see that the value for `%i` is constant but `%j` changes within a single invocation depending on the unit file.  To me this is unintuitive and I have been unable to find any systemd documentation which states that this behaviour is expected.

I understand that I could copy `/lib/systemd/system/foo@.service` to `/etc/systemd/system/foo@.service` and edit it - I'm just trying to use recommended practices here.

Does anyone know if the changing values for `%j` is an accepted behaviour or am I simply abusing/confusing systemd with my symlink?